# Vulkan validation error when trying to create 2D array image view for 3D image

Tags: vulkan

I need to create a `VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D_ARRAY` image view for an image of type `VK_IMAGE_TYPE_3D` so that I can render to each slice of the image in a render pass (selecting the layer / slice in the geometry shader).

From this [link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkImageViewCreateInfo.html) in the Vulkan spec, the table seems to imply (last entry of the table) that if I create an image with `VK_IMAGE_TYPE_3D`, `arrayLayers = 1` and with flags including `VK_IMAGE_CREATE_2D_ARRAY_COMPATIBLE_BIT`, I should be able to create an image view with `VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D_ARRAY`, with multiple layers (`layerCount >= 1` and in my case, the amount of layers would be the depth of the extent of the 3D image).

With all these parameters set, I am getting the following validation errors:

```
Validation layer (2;4096): Validation Error: [ VUID-VkImageViewCreateInfo-subresourceRange-01719 ] Object 0: handle = 0x410000000041, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_IMAGE; | MessageID = 0x1510053d | vkCreateImageView: pCreateInfo->subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer + .layerCount (= 0 + 32 = 32) is greater than the arrayLayers of the image when it was created (i.e. greater than 1). The Vulkan spec states: If subresourceRange.layerCount is not VK_REMAINING_ARRAY_LAYERS, subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer + subresourceRange.layerCount must be less than or equal to the arrayLayers specified in VkImageCreateInfo when image was created (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.154.0/linux/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkImageViewCreateInfo-subresourceRange-01719)

Validation layer (2;4096): Validation Error: [ VUID-VkImageViewCreateInfo-subResourceRange-01021 ] Object 0: handle = 0x410000000041, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_IMAGE; | MessageID = 0x835d4826 | vkCreateImageView(): pCreateInfo->viewType VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D_ARRAY is not compatible with image type VK_IMAGE_TYPE_3D. The Vulkan spec states: subresourceRange and viewType must be compatible with the image, as described in the compatibility table (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.154.0/linux/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkImageViewCreateInfo-subResourceRange-01021)
```

I don't see why it says that `VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D_ARRAY` is not compatible with image type `VK_IMAGE_TYPE_3D` given I gave the `VK_IMAGE_CREATE_2D_ARRAY_COMPATIBLE_BIT` flag to the image... Plus the spec table said I could do so...

I don't know maybe there is something I misunderstood in the spec.

Comment: Have you enabled Vulkan 1.1 or `VK_KHR_maintenance1` extension?

Comment: Ah enabling Vulkan 1.1 worked! Thanks